# How to avoid installing all centos packages everytime I run gitlab ci pipeline?

Tags: caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm running a gitlab ci pipeline with a Centos image.
The pipeline has a before script that runs a set of commands.

**gitlab-ci.yaml**

```
variables:
  WORKSPACE_HOME: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR'
  DELIVERY_HOME: delivery
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

default:
  image: centos:latest

  cache:
    paths:
      - .cache/pip

  before_script:
    - chmod u+x devops/scripts/*.sh
    - devops/scripts/install-ci.sh
    - python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
    - cp .env.docker.dist .env
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

**install-ci.yaml**

```
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-* &&\
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-*
yum -y update
yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ make
yum -y install python3.8
yum install python3-setuptools
yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum -y install python3-devel
yum -y install postgresql-server
yum -y install postgresql-devel
yum -y install postgresql-libs
yum -y install python3-pip
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris
yum -y install sqlite-devel
```

The issue is that everytime I run the ci pipeline it takes time to install centos and all it's packages.
Is there a way to avoid this ? or cache this operation somewhere ?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own image in which all your dependencies are installed and use this in your job instead of installing the dependencies all over again. I would create a dedicated project on your gitlab instance, something like "centos-python-postgress" and within this project you create a `Dockerfile` in which you install everything you need. (You can either copy your install-ci.sh or RUN the commands directly within your dockerfile) :

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-* && sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-*
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ make
...
```

You can now either build the `Dockerfile` on your machine and push it manually to the container registry in this project or you create a CI Pipeline that builds and pushes that image automatically:

```
 stages:
   - build

  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - >-
      /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest"
```

Now, Instead of using `centos:latest` in your origin project/job, you can use your own image:

```
variables:
  WORKSPACE_HOME: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR'
  DELIVERY_HOME: delivery
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
    
default:
   image: registry.gitlab.com/snowfire/centos-python-postgress:latest
   cache:
     paths:
        - .cache/pip
   before_script:
        - ...
```